# How to avoid dispatchTouchEvent being called when click button

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-button, touch-event

In my Activity, I have an `EditText` and a `Button`.  I overrided the `dispatchTouchEvent` to hide the soft keyboard when click the other area of the screen than the `EditText`.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w
                        .getBottom())) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The issue is, every time I click the `Button`, the `dispatchTouchEvent` will be called, so the soft keyboard will disappear, which is not what I want.  I don't want to hide the keyboard when I click the `Button`.  What I'm thinking is that is it possible to avoid calling the `dispatchTouchEvent` when I click the `Button`?

Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add logic to detect the coordinates of the `Button` too? Or if the rest of the layout is not-interactive, you can just a touch listener on the main layout to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the dispatchTouch event. Just set the onClickListener of you activity to the same with the Button and EditText, then call the methods to hide the softkeyboard on the "default" case of the switch case.

```
switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button:
            whateverButtonDoes();
            break;
        case R.id.editText:
            whateverEditTextDoes();
            break;
        default:
            hideKeyboard();
            break;
    }
```

I strongly suggest you define a method to hide the keyboard for clear coding standards. Also you might use it elsewhere.

Comment: v.getid() inside dispatchTouchEvent is coming different than R.id.button which is my button can you please tell me why this is happening ??